# Warning: set_error_handler() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in bin/magento on line 21

Tags: magento2.3, setup-upgrade, magento-upgrade

I have ungraded my Magento 2.2.x Store to Magento 2.3. After upgrade everything was working fine. I have observed a new issue in PHP CLI.

Once I run any CLI command I am getting PHP Warning Like below:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
Warning: set_error_handler() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in bin/magento on line 21
```

After that command works properly.

I am using the correct PHP CLI version: `PHP 7.2.15 (cli)`

I have no idea how this new warning get occurred and how to fix this.

Also I observed that a log file get created on my root folder with **php_error log** where the above warning is getting appended.

Can someone help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
php56 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

php version 5.6 which is required in Magento 2. Hope this would help